# Mayer-Vietoris of pair (X,C)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to know if i can use Mayer-Vietoris with this form:

Let X be a topological space and A, B be two subspaces whose interiors cover X and  $C\subset A\cap B$.

We get the exact sequence

$... \rightarrow H_q(A\cap B,C)\rightarrow H_q(A,C)\oplus H_q(B,C)\rightarrow H_q(X,C) \rightarrow ...$

It is true? i am trying to solve a problem of homology groups and i get stuck, and if this is true that could help me solve it, i would appreciate any comment

Comment: Is this maybe a consequence of [long exact sequence of a relative triple](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Long_exact_sequence_of_homology_of_a_triple)?

Comment: @DanielRust could you explain some more please?

Comment: Yes, look at the "relative form" in the wikipedia article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer–Vietoris_sequence#Relative_form

Comment: @Timkinsella Thanks, i only knew the version with the intersection in the right member of $H_q(X,C)$ but seems that this version is also true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take $C = D = Y$ here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence#Relative_form

For a proof, see p. 152 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).